# Sorting complex list of strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I feel it would be better to illustrate my problem, so here it is:

I have this list:

```
['1.2.3', '1.2.4', '10.3', '1.3', '12', '14.12.123', '4', '6']
```

and would like it sorted like so:

```
['1.2.3', '1.2.4', '1.3', '4', '6', '10.3', '12', '14.12.123']
```

As you can see I would like to sort initially by the first digit then the second and so on. Also there could be an infinite amount of digits in the list items(e.g. `'1.2.3.4.5.6'` and so on)

I have tried the usual sorted method to no avail, and cannot find a similar situation  on the internet to help me out.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you seen all the `key` parameter to `sorted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

`sorted(l, key=lambda k: [int(num) for num in k.split('.')])`

Comment: @NehalJWani: nope.

Comment: Why not? Do you have any better idea?